# How does a PeerName relate to a Peer created when opening a channel using NetPeerTcpBinding?

Tags: wcf, p2p, net.p2p

I have read the articles (specifically [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc297274.aspx#WCFP2P_topic7)) and worked with the peer-to-peer examples from Microsoft but I cannot find anything that explains how registering a [peer name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.peertopeer.peername.aspx) relates to actually opening up a peer channel. Can anyone explain?